# Showing the equality of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $B$ is a finite ball in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $f \in L^1(B)$, why do we have the following equality:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}(\int_{\{|f| > \frac{t}{2}\}}|f(x)|dx) dt = \int_B (
\int_1^{\text{max}\{2|f(x)|, 1\}} \frac{1}{t}dt)|f(x)|dx$$

This equality is showing up in the proof of the statement:

> The maximal function of $f$ is in $L^1(B)$ iff $|f|\log(e + |f|) \in L^1(B)$

But I don't understand the above equality. I would appreciate any help in understanding it!

Comment: Step 1: Write all boundaries of the integrals as indicator functions (so, rewrite $\int_{|f| > t/2} ...$ as $\int_B 1_{|f(x)|>t/2}$). Step 2: Use Fubini's theorem. Step 3: Rewrite the indicator function as integral boundaries, this time for the integral over $t$.